# Network Configuration WebInterface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, web-applications

I'm search a simple webinterface for manage the network configuration of an ubuntu server. On default our machines are on dhcp. But i want the option to change to an fix ipaddress. Is there nothing available for this task? I have only found this project for ubuntu core https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/device-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a universal tool for my problem. https://cockpit-project.org/running